# GLCanvas and other JOGL classes missing from NetBeans OpenGL Pack?

Tags: java, opengl, netbeans, jogl, netbeans-plugins

I'm have horrendous problems trying to get a JOGL program compiling using Netbeans 6.9. I can't seem to find an up to date explanation as to how to do this. When I install the NetBeans OpenGL pack I can't compile the examples. I get a compile error stating it can't find some methods such as GLCanvas(). When I go to the library to see if the GLCanvas class is there I find that it's not!

Can anybody help me out and show me how I can setup JOGL with Netbeans? I'd GREATLY appreciate it!

Many thanks,

Comment: Have you followed these steps? http://cs.gmu.edu/~jchen/graphics/jogl/notes/joglSetup.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just tried following those steps and still no luck. Those steps don't mention NetBeans either.

I think I might be having trouble setting my classpath too. Every time I call "export CLASSPATH=/users/james/jars/jogl.jar" and echo the classpath back it seems fine. But when I reopen the terminal and echo the classpath it's empty (I'm on Mac OS 10.6)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jogamp.762907.n3.nabble.com/JOGL-tt963769.html#a976919

Comment: The stuff in that post worked for me! Thanks very, very much!